# Compact Framework call Input Method Options with p/invoke

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, pinvoke

I have implemented a p/invoke command in my compact framework based application which invokes the windows calibrate screen.

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private extern static bool TouchCalibrate();

btnAlignScreen.Click += delegate
        {
            TouchCalibrate();
        };
```

Does anyone know the p/invoke command to invoke the input settings screen located in Settings -> Input.  Windows Mobile 6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open up settings applets in the control panel by using the `\Windows\ctlpnl.exe` executable along with the proper command line arguments.

This [link](http://www.pcoperative.com/ppc/wm_shortcuts.htm) provides a list of the command line arguments used in the shortcuts in the control panel.

This example opens up the input method tab in the input settings control panel applet:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"\Windows\ctlpnl.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguements = "cplmain.cpl,8";
myProcess.Start();
```